# 100% width in css is not working in lower screen resolution

Tags: css

I am doing a project http://damiracle.com/clientdemos/site_ibfa/
where I am using the header panel width 100%.

```
    #header
{

    width:100%;
    height:829px;
    /*background:url(../images/head2.png) repeat-x;*/
    background:#000;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    margin-bottom:10px; 



    }
```

Everything is working fine when it is big screen resolution but when it is a smaller screen resolution it is showing a white space in the right side. I have tried by all means.
I have writen a global css

```
html,body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {margin:0;padding:0; border:0;font-size:100%; font:inherit; vertical-align:baseline;}
```

but then also it is not working.
I shall be obliged if any one helps me to sort it out.
Thanks in advance to all of you

Comment: what the hack 4.8 mb of site ??its too much big

Comment: you are creating site with 1200 px i think you are checking this site on more than 1200px resolution's 1200 px isnt standard

Comment: Try to Optimize images and Css. 5.0MB!

Comment: Yes NullPointer Iam creating the site in 1200px width but in higher screen it is showing perfect but in less than 1200px screen with it is creating problem

Comment: why do not you use css3 media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Add `min-width:1200px;` to your `#header`

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:829px;
    background:#000;
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    min-width: 1200px;
}
```

P.S: you can use one background image for all blocks! optimize you site. For title in blocks use `img` with `alt`(it's good path for SEO and users with disabled images), like this:

```
<img src="/images/destination-egypt.png" alt="Destination Egypt"/>
```

or for more optimize use [CSS-sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: Thanks Belyash I have added min-width & width before but same is also happening

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `#headerTOP` has a `width: 1200px` .
So your `#header` just get the size 100% size of the screensize. But your `#headerTOP` will always be larger than that if the screenwidth is lower than `1200px`.